# How to change Magento widget title

Tags: css, magento, magento-1.9

I've inserted in a widget to display new product on my Home page it shows perfect but I would like to remove the widget title "New Product".

This little devil need to be removed

[image]

I am not able to correctly locate the widget file in root to remove the title. I found the file in app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/widget/new/column but heck it is not working. I tried to comment out or edit the description to something else but it does not change.

Where is the correct file located? Help..I'm using Magento 1.9

Comment: Is the site configured to use RWD?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are using the correct package such as RWD or default.  Then you want to enable template hints in the configuration menu (you might want to google how to do this).  Go to the page with that widget, and take a close look to where what .phtml file is being used.  At this point you should override that file according to magento best practices.  Never edit default templates, always create your own theme and put the modified version in there.  So anyways, once you find and override that file it should be fairly what to remove unless you are not familiar with php.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the translation of the combination of words "New Product" in the locale here: `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Widget.csv`.

If you want to give each widget a unique name.Please visit below URL, hope it's helpful for you.

http://code.mytodayaz.com/magento/how-can-i-modify-or-clone-the-8220-new-products-8221-widget-so-title-is-8220-featured-products-63-8221--42915.html